# Thread safe getter/setter in mailbox

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, system

How would you implement the following mailbox system in a thread-safe way in Python? Is setting/getting variables "atomic" or can I get a variable overwritten at the same time I am reading it?

I have a set of objects that can get/send information trough the SAME socket. To have multiple objects settings/getting values at "the same time" I was thinking to use some kind of mailbox system.

Instead of sending info trough the socket directly from each object each will write the command to send in a mailbox. Another thread will constantly go trough the mailbox in a fifo manner sending each command trough the socket and putting in each one a message with the answer. Therefore to get information the object will request it by writting for example to a dictionary the command and monitor until it gets a reply in the dictionary.

Do I need to implement a lock system to prevent two objects writting at the same time to the mailbox or getting corrupted information from it or will Python "magically" handle it?

I think Python will handle it correctly without needing to implement a lock as I only nead to read once or write once or add to list once and that is atomic from http://effbot.org/zone/thread-synchronization.htm#atomic-operations

Comment: Writing and reading of core data types is atomic.  http://effbot.org/zone/thread-synchronization.htm#atomic-operations   Would you like to edit your question and explain what exactly it is you are trying to build and achieve here. This might be better solved by more advanced data types, for example queues.

Comment: Yes, I found the same link so I think it's fine to use without any lock.

I have a socket to send receive data and I need other threads running that need to send and receive data trough it independently. Data is very simple just to set a value or get a value so I can encode it in a mailbox easily.

Comment: And each thread waits for the response when makes a request (by polling the mailbox continouly)

Comment: If you have several threads writing to the same socket, I would assume there is no guarantee of the consistency of the socket data. I doubt writing a buffer of data to a socket is atomic, so if two threads are writing at the same time, the output from the socket might be mangled.

Comment: A much better way to do this would be using a single thread that writes to the socket. It would listen to a queue and as soon as there is a message in queue, it would read it and write to socket. All threads that need to communicate with the socket would then use this queue. This is how I would do it but if your method works, by all means use it. There is no one true and correct way.

Comment: Thats what I propose. I havent implemented it yet. A mailbox/queue and each thread writes there and another one (single) monitors the mailbox and performs the socket actions and puts the reply there. Each object must be independent, theres no sequence. This will work and you also shggested the same, Im asking the pythonic way :)

Comment: I think this is a relatively pythonic way to do this. Threads in python are not good performers but they help when you need to separate tasks for example the reason you have: to ensure consistency when accessing a shared resource. I did not understand the concept "mailbox" and was not sure what it meant.